# simple way to calculate average by union of three tables using MySQL and php

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have three database tables

```
        Graduate_survey
      g_id(pk)AI  PO  PO1  PO2 Program_name year1 year2

        Alumni_survey
      a_id(pk)AI  PO  PO1  PO2 Program_name year1 year2

        faculty_survey
      f_id(pk)AI  PO  PO1  PO2 Program_name year1 year2
```

after inserting the values into these tables i need to calculate the average and store the average value in another table total_survey

```
   total_survey
   t_id(pk)AI  PO  PO1  PO2 Program_name year1 year2
```

The Program_name, year1, year2 are inserted using `$_session`. 
 How to calculate the average using MySQL query and store the new value in another table using php? My codes are given below but it is not working.

```
             <?php
             @include("connection.php");
             error_reporting(0);
             $program=$_POST['Program_name'];
             $year1=$_POST["year1"];
             $year2=$_POST["year2"];
             $po=$_POST["total_PO"];
             $po1=$_POST["total_PO1"];
             $po2=$_POST["total_PO2"];
             $_SESSION['SProgram_name']=$program;
             $_SESSION['Syear1']=$year1;
             $_SESSION['Syear2']=$year2;
             if($_POST['submit'])
            {
              $sql= "SELECT AVG(t.PO) AS total_PO, AVG(t.PO1) AS 
              total_PO1, AVG(t.PO2) AS total_PO2
              FROM ( SELECT PO,PO1,PO2
              FROM Graduate_survey
              UNION ALL
              SELECT PO,PO1,PO2
              FROM alumni_survey
              UNION ALL
              SELECT PO,PO1,PO2
              FROM faculty_survey
              )*t";
             $rData=mysql_query($sql);
             $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);

              $sql="select * from total_survey";
             $rData=mysql_query($sql);
             $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
             $sql="insert into total_survey 
            values('','$po','$po1','$po2','$program','$year1','$year2')";
             mysql_query($sql);

             }
            ?>
           <form method="post">
           <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click 
           here to calculate the final indirect assesment">
           </form>
```

suppose in the graduate_survey table the PO column contain 70, PO1 contain 60 and PO2 contain 80. In the alumni_survey the PO column contain 60, PO1 contain 70 and PO2 contain 90.In the faculty_survey the PO column contain 90, PO1 contain 80 and PO2 contain 60. All i need is Average(PO+PO+PO), Average(PO1+PO1+PO1), Average(PO2+PO2+PO2) by union of all the three table group by ID

Comment: What do you want to insert? avgerage of averages? That does not make much sense honestly

Comment: avg, avg1, avg2 these are column names....Graduate_survey, alumni_survey and faculty_survey are some survey forms where some average calculation is done and have to store it in database... now i need to sum up the columns of these databases and take averages of them...For example in Graduate_survey avg,avg1,avg2 contain some numarical values and same in Alumni_survey and faculty_survey. Now i need is average of avg(graduate_survey)+avg(alumni_survey)+avg(faculty_survey)/3...same in case of avg1 and avg2......and the average value will have to store in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do average on `UNION`s and wrap it into `INSERT` query, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO total_survey (PO, PO1, PO2)
SELECT AVG(PO), AVG(PO1), AVG(PO2) 
FROM (
 SELECT PO, PO1, PO2 FROM graduate_survey

 UNION

 SELECT PO, PO1, PO2 FROM Alumni_survey

 UNION

 SELECT PO, PO1, PO2 FROM faculty_survey
) a;
```

Comment: I have to do it with php code....First i have to calculate the average and then insert the new average value....My code is not working...it shows that datas are inserted but all zero values that means the average calculation query doesnot working..

Comment: you take it wrongly...This is not average of averages....Let me tell you briefly....suppose

Comment: you take it wrongly...This is not average of averages....Let me tell you briefly....suppose  as per the above question in the graduate_survey table the PO column contain 70, PO1 contain 60 and PO2 contain 80. In the alumni_survey the PO column contain 60, PO1 contain 70 and PO2 contain 90.In the faculty_survey the PO column contain 90, PO1 contain 80 and PO2 contain 60. All i need is Average(PO+PO+PO), Average(PO1+PO1+PO1), Average(PO2+PO2+PO2) by union of all the three table group by ID.

Comment: select query totally works. Question is which query have to be written first? Insert or select...because the values that are fetched from the three table have to be inserted.

Comment: Both `INSERT` and `SELECT` are parts of the same query. The whole `INSERT.. SELECT` needs to be executed together.

Comment: Yes it's done already...thank you...I have a question...I have a table program( Id(pk), program name, session), and these survey tables....now can I make the Id of program table foreign key constraint to these survey tables...But the problem is one foreign key constraint only points to exactly one parent table....so how can I make the data's of these Survey table consistent?

Comment: Each survey will have a `program_id`. Also, by making it foreign key, you will establish many to one relationship so mapping multiple surveys against the same program will work fine.